# remove initial wysiwyg editor from cms page edit

Tags: custom-field, page-template, wysiwyg

So I have successfully installed and implemented the Advanced Custom Fields plugin from: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

I have applied a set of custom fields to a custom page template, successfully.

What Im trying to do now is remove the initial text input field from the page, but I haven't a clue where to start, here is what I mean...

[image]

As you can see, the advanced custom fields "addition fields" are there but it is retaining the initial input box.

How do I go about removing this? any pointers or help welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, third party plugins are off-topic for this site.

However this is an easy one - in the Custom Fields page in the admin area, go into your field group. Scroll right down to the bottom and there's a section allowing you to "hide" elements in the post.

Select the "content" option here and you're done.

Keep in mind that if you have multiple field groups on the one post, you will need to hide the elements you want on the the *first* visible field group.

Comment: Ha! i actually found this straight after posting my question, after hours of googling :/ thanks for answering though it is appreciated! will accept when I can (10 mins)

Comment: @AndrewBramwell Glad you found it!